# XSLT2 format-dateTime - AM/PM without dots/periods

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, formatdatetime

This is a question for XSLT 2 format-dateTime function.

Please can anyone tell me how to make A.M./P.M. display with not dots/periods (AM/PM)?

```
<xsl:variable name="ampm" select="format-dateTime(DATE, '[PN]')"/>
```

The below code returns blank?

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($ampm,'.','')"/>
```

Thanks, Will

Answer (score 1):

```
format-dateTime(DATE, '[PN,2-2]')
```

will output AM/PM on some XSLT 2 implementations.

The format string specifies that the output should be exactly 2 character.

Answer (score 0):

translate works

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($ampm,'.','')"/>
```